# Registering the Bitmap data to a printer

Tags: c#, printing, serial-port

I want to print a bitmap to my printer(Citizen PD 24). 
For printing the bitmap i have to register this **image** into the printer. 
as the manual available they are mentioning us to use the following Command Sequence

`Esc~bFFh n1 n2 d1 d2.`

The problem is that i don't know how to use these `n1, n2, d1, d2`. 
Please any one help me on this issue. 
 i am using C#

Regards 
Biju

Answer (score 0):

> You can use PrintDocument, maybe this
>   code help you.

```
   PrintPreviewControl printPreviewControl = new PrintPreviewControl();
                PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
                printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument_PrintPage);
                printPreviewControl.Document = printDocument;


            void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage("SomeBitmap", 0,0);
            }
```

Comment: hi @hashi:  Thanks for the reply. I am trying to print this through a Mobile device to my printer. the print is happneing through an serial port. So will this help me?